# how to calculate average total score by country

Tags: excel

I have this below data in my excel,

```
Country Question 1  Question 2  Question 3  Total
Australia   10  10  10  30
Australia   7   10  7   24
Hong Kong   7   7   7   21
Japan   5   5   0   10
Australia   10  7   5   22
Hong Kong   7   7   7   21
Hong Kong   7   7   7   21
Australia   7   10  10  27
Australia   7   10  7   24
```

I need to find out the average total score by country. How should I calculate that? Or maybe someone can just tell me the formula for it. Sorry I am not good in excel and math :\

Comment: [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-FAEC8E2E-0DEC-4308-AF69-F5576D8AC642)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-FAEC8E2E-0DEC-4308-AF69-F5576D8AC642) in excel.

In the cell below all the totals do:

```
=AVERAGEIF(range, criteria, [average_range])
```